# How to keep the activity in its current state when switching?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I have two activities A and B in my android app written in Kotlin. Activity B has a RecycleView. Activity B is launched from activity A using the startActivity() method when you click on the button to go to this activity. Imagine the following sequence of actions:

1. I launch Activity B and scroll through the RecycleView to some element.
2. Then I use the back button on the phone to go back to activity A.
3. Then I click on the button again to go to activity B and launch activity B.

I need that when action 3 occurs, RecyclingView is displayed from the place where it stopped at action 1. That is, so that the activity is not destroyed during action 2, and then re-created when switching to it again, but that it remains in its current state and just switch back to it.

How i can to do it?

Many here in the answers advise using the onSaveInstanceState method, but as far as I know, the method using onSaveInstanceState only works when the android system itself terminates the process (for example, due to lack of memory) or if the screen orientation changes. But if the user himself closed the activity B using the "back" button, then onSaveInstanceState does not work in this case.

Comment: If you open the Activity again via `startActivity`, all of the state is created again from scratch. Your best bet would be to save the `RecyclerView`'s scroll position to a static variable somewhere in your codebase only for current session or use `SharedPreference` or `Datastore` if you want that behaviour for future sessions as well.

Comment: So, do you want to terminate the first-launched activity B and the recreate a new one?

Comment: @PhantomLord No, as long as the user stays inside the app and hasn't closed the app by swiping from the list of recent apps, I need the activities to not be destroyed, but to keep their state so that I can simply switch between them without creating them again with each switch.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas.

0. Just don't. This is non-standard behavior and the path of least resistance is to just let the system work and move on to more important things.
1. You could launch B with `startActivityForResult` with the "last known scroll position", defaulting to 0. Then B could return the `RecyclerView` position as the result for A to keep track of. Next time you launch, pass it *back* to B to set the scroll position.
2. Save the position in some kind of global state object: static int, singleton, or your `Application` class instance. Read from that when you start B and set it when you leave B.
3. If you want this to persist between app restarts, save to persistent storage on closing B (`SharedPreferences` would be the easiest option) and read back when opening B.

Edit: Based on your comment.

4. Intercept the back button press in activity B and launch activity A with "single top" and / or "reorder to front" flag(s) to keep B alive but in the background. Similarly, launch B with the same flags to bring the existing instant back to the front.

This is firmly in "dirty hack" territory because, again, this is non-standard behavior.

Comment: If you mean to save the scroll position in order to restore it later through the scrollToPosition method, then this is not exactly the behavior that I want, because in this case, activity B is re-created when you switch to it again and then simply scrolls programmatically to a certain position. What I want to achieve is that when I move to Activity A from Activity B, Activity B stays in its state, then on the reverse transition, it simply continues from where it left off.

Comment: For example, a similar behavior occurs when I minimize the application while in activity B, switch to another application and then switch back to my application from the list of recent ones, in this case, activity B simply continues from where it left off when minimized, and does not start again . I need exactly the same behavior when switching between activities inside the app.

Comment: Why do you need this? This is not how Android works. But I added a 4th option as a hack if you insist.

Answer (score 0):

alright, then if the user click the back button, you must intercept the onDestroy event, or onBackPressed or onStop and cancel the event and simply hide the activity. I don't remember if to cancel an event is sufficient to avoid to call the super. Remember to unload correctly all the activities when the app finish a to avoid memory leak